# The increment of a pointer does not work. It's quite hard for me to understand what's what

Tags: c++, pointers, types, increment

I have recently learned some basics of pointers in C++. So I understand that an array's name is just simply a pointer set to the first position of the array by default. And I do not really comprehend why the first code works just fine whereas the second code shows an error on the line: `tab = tab+1;`

Could you explain to me why it's so ambiguous?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int *tab;
    tab = new int[5] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *tab << std::endl;
        tab++;
    }

    delete []tab;
}
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int tab[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *tab << std::endl;
        tab = tab+1; // ERROR
    }
}
```

Comment: "shows an error" - what's the error?

Comment: *"I understand that an array's name is just simply a pointer"*. This is wrong.

Comment: arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays. Arrays do decay to pointers to the first element when eg passed to a function, but `tab` is an array

Comment: I actually hate the wording of "decays to a pointer" - I believe it's more accurate to say unadorned arrays actually decay to an *address* - the address of the first element.  And an *address* is not an lvalue - an address is not a chunk of memory you can put a value in - an address *is* a value.  As for "arrays are pointers" - again, NO.  arrays are chunks of actual memory that **have** an address that's valid - the array exists.  Pointers are *variables* that **hold** an address - and the address held in a pointer may or may not be valid.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Well, the standard calls it "decay to pointer" ([1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.array#:conversion,array-to-pointer), [2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#const.cast-example-1)). Usually I see "an address" being used to refer to values of pointer objects, just like "a number" is a value of an object of an arithmetic type. So "decays to pointer" is ok in my book, if you keep in mind that said pointer is a prvalue. *"Pointers are variables"* With such wording, `int *x[5];` is not an array of "pointers", because the elements are not variables but mere objects.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat True, but I'm trying to simplify the explanation.  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The first code "works" because `tab` is declared as an actual pointer, and you can assign another pointer to it. But the code also fails, because it has undefined behavior due to `tab` no longer pointing at the original memory returned by `new[]` when `delete[]` is called.

The second code does not work because `tab` is declared as an array, not a pointer. It *decays* into a pointer when needed, but you can't assign a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 1):

> So I understand that an array's name is just simply a pointer set to the first position of it by default.

No. That is wrong. Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays.

Because arrays can decay to the address of its first elements you can write `int* tab_ptr = tab;` to get a pointer to the first element:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int tab[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    int* tab_ptr = tab;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *tab_ptr << std::endl;
        tab_ptr = tab_ptr+1;
    }
}
```

And because arrays do decay to the address of its first element when passed to functions you can also do this:

```
#include <iostream>

void foo(int t[]){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << *t << std::endl;
        t = t+1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int tab[5] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    foo(tab);
}
```

When you write `tab = tab+1` you get the error:

```
<source>:23:13: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int [5]'
   23 |         tab = tab+1;
      |         ~~~~^~~~~~~
```

because the array does decay to an address in `tab+1`, and `tab+1` is a pointer, but you cannot assign the resulting pointer to the array `tab`.

The first version does not have this problem, because there `tab` is indeed a pointer to a dynamic array.

Comment: okay thx for all anwers but I got a different question regarding second code. If I wrote             *(tab+i) why would it work?

Comment: @Quarol because `tab+i` is a pointer to i-th element. `*(tab+i)` is the same as `tab[i]`